# Q-municate-web out of the box does not find friends

Tags: q-municate

We can not find facebook contacts in the web app. This is what we have done:

- Registered new QB app in dashboard
- Registered new Facebook app (add domain, make public, verify user_friends active etc)
- Entered FB app/secret to QB
- Installed https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-web
- Updateed config.js with appid, key, secret, FacebookID etc
- Login with facebook verified, users are then visible in the QB dashboard
- Two facebook-friends registers/logins.
- Global friends search for eachother: no results.

Doing this search on q-municate demo web app we can find eachother.
Did I miss some config or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check "Allow to retrieve a list of users" in the quickblox dashboard.
Its a bit tricky to find it though. In your app, click Overview, then Settings in the top right corner. Good luck!

Comment: yay! that was it. awesome. Thank you!